# DataFrame transformation: from multiple columns to one

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, transform

How can I transform with **Pandas** & **NumPy** this DataFrame:

[image: initial table]

to DataFrame like:

```
        Name      Year     Nb 
------+--------+--------+-------
0     |  A     |   2021 |  5.0
1     |  A     |   2020 |  4.0
2     |  A     |   2019 | 10.0
3     |  A     |   2018 |  4.0
4     |  A     |   2017 |  4.0
...
k     |  A-Jay |   2021 |  5.0
k+1   |  A-Jay |   2020 |  6.0
...
l+i   |  A.J.  |   2019 |  3.0
m     |  Aaban |   2021 |  4.0
m+1   |  Aaban |   2020 |  4.0
...
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a way (probably the most elegant) using `melt()`:

```py
out = ( df
    .melt(id_vars='Name', var_name='Year', value_name='Nb')
    .dropna()
    .sort_values(['Name','Year'], ascending=[True,False])
    .reset_index(drop=True) )
```

Here's another way, this one using `stack()`:

```py
out = ( df
    .set_index('Name')
    .stack()
    .reset_index()
    .rename(columns={'level_1':'Year',0:'Nb'})
    .sort_values(['Name','Year'],ascending=[True,False])
    .reset_index(drop=True) )
```

Sample input:

```
  Name  2021  2022  2023  2024
0    a   NaN   4.0  None   0.0
1    b   2.0   NaN  None   NaN
2    c   3.0   6.0  None   0.0
```

Output:

```
  Name  Year   Nb
0    a  2024  0.0
1    a  2022  4.0
2    b  2021  2.0
3    c  2024  0.0
4    c  2022  6.0
5    c  2021  3.0
```